# Return array based on value of column in source array

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to obtain an array of only values that meet certain criteria.

I have an array in which the meeting of these criteria is summarised in a column of TRUE/FALSE for each entry, as such

```
INDEX MEETS_CRITERIA
1     TRUE
2     TRUE
3     FALSE
4     FALSE
5     FALSE
6     TRUE
7     TRUE
8     TRUE
9     FALSE
10    FALSE
```

I wish to obtain, in a separate sheet, a list, without gaps, of all indexes that have true in the column "MEETS_CRITERIA", as below

```
INDEX
1
2
6
7
8
```

I am attempting this with the below array formula:

```
{=INDEX(ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$A$2:$A$10, MATCH("TRUE",ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$B$2:$B$10, 0))}
```

However this returns #N/A.

What is the error in my formula or my approach?

Comment: TRUE is a Boolean value and as such doesn't need the quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the observation by Clif, your current formula would in any case only be suitable for providing a single return, not the list you give.

For that you would require (assuming you have Excel 2010 or later):

`=INDEX(ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$B$2:$B$10)/ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$B$2:$B$10,ROWS($1:1)))`

and copied down.

As to masking errors, then, assuming the example you give is representative of your actual set-up - in that there are only a dozen or so rows in the source data - you can afford an otherwise inefficient IFERROR set-up, viz:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$B$2:$B$10)/ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$B$2:$B$10,ROWS($1:1))),"")`

If the data range in question is in fact quite large, then it will be much preferable to use an additional cell somewhere in the sheet, e.g. D1, in which a single formula is used to determine the expected number of returns, viz:

`=COUNTIF(ORIGINAL_ARRAY!B2:B10,TRUE)`

which can then be referenced in the main formula itself i.e.:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>D$1,"",INDEX(ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$B$2:$B$10)/ORIGINAL_ARRAY!$B$2:$B$10,ROWS($1:1))))`

and will be far more efficient than the IFERROR set-up, for reasons (if you're interested) explained here:

[Look up a value in a list and return ALL multiple corresponding values](https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values/812848#812848)

Regards

Comment: Works perfectly and went above and beyond with the error checking. An excellent answer. Many thanks for your assistance.